# attempt to compare nil < number?

Tags: lua, roblox

Im trying to change to get the zamount's value in the client side but it returns it as nil, can anyone help??

script:

```
script.Parent.MouseClick:Connect(function(plr)
if plr.Team == game.Teams.Mastermind then
    local zombiespawn = script.Parent.Parent
    game.ReplicatedStorage.Events:WaitForChild("Onzombiespawnclick"):FireAllClients(plr,script.Parent.Parent.CFrame ,zombiespawn)
end
end)
```

Local script:

```
game.ReplicatedStorage.Events:WaitForChild("Onzombiespawnclick").OnClientEvent:Connect(function(spawncframe, zombiespawn)
script.Parent.Visible = true
zombiespawnreference = spawncframe

zombieamountreference = zombiespawn:FindFirstChild("Zombieamount").Value
end)




if zombieamountreference < game.ReplicatedStorage.Vals:WaitForChild("Zombieamountlimit").Value then
            if not debounce then
                debounce = true
                script.Parent:WaitForChild("Placeevent"):FireServer(zombiename, zombiespawnreference, power, zombieamountreference)
                wait(0.3)
                debounce = false
            end
        end
```

Comment: Please post it as text

Comment: done, i couldnt fit them before so sorry

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind, i had to put a player object on the client event parameter thing. Its fixed now

Comment: it will be good if you update the final code or whatever correction you done as solution, for rest of people.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).